# C3 graph displaying issue in Angular Material Layout

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, flexbox, angular-material, c3.js

I have an strange issue with displaying graphs in AMD Layout.
There are two widgets in which I've defined graphs and here is how it looks like - you can see that graphs in widgets go out of their area
[image]

I've tried reproduce this bug in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zhOwHnHdXDh1UryJzxfz?p=preview) and there is nothing wrong :/

When I make a small change in browser (for example, I move the edge of the browser), graphs return to the right place -> http://recordit.co/mRmNAjH840

```
<div layout="row" ng-controller="GraphCtrl" layout-md="column" layout-sm="column" layout-margin="">

    <section class="widget md-whiteframe-z1 ng-isolate-scope md-cyan-theme" ng-class="{'widget-overlay-title': overlayTitle}" ng-attr-layout="{{widgetLayout}}" content-padding="" flex-gt-lg="66" flex-gt-md="66">
        <div class="panel-heading">Widget1<span flex=""></span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="chart1"></div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="widget md-whiteframe-z1 ng-isolate-scope md-cyan-theme" ng-class="{'widget-overlay-title': overlayTitle}" ng-attr-layout="{{widgetLayout}}" content-padding="" flex-gt-lg="32" flex-gt-md="32">
        <div class="panel-heading">Widget2<span flex=""></span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="c3_combined"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps the `c3_combined` and `chart1` divs are being resized somehow after the charts are rendered.

Comment: Hm, I've included [c3-angular-directive](http://jettro.github.io/c3-angular-directive/) and with directive looks ok :/

Comment: I also noticed that at lower resolutions (smartphones) looks ok without c3-angular-directive

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is related to your problem, but on IE, I have to add this CSS property manually :

`svg { overflow: hidden; }`